# How could I vary the temperature of a liquid whilst conducting tests on its viscosity?

Tags: experimental-physics

Is there a way to accurately control the temperature of a liquid whilst conducting a ball drop experiment on it to determine how its viscosity would be affected by its temperature?

How should I design my experiment if I do not have overly complicated mechanisms at my disposal?

My current set-up involves heating the liquid in a water bath to 2 or 3 degrees celsius above the desired temperature, removing the liquid and using a thermometer, wait till the temperature cools to the desired one before quickly conducting the experiment. Then repeating.

How could I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly respectable way of doing the experiment. When you design any experimental protocol you decide how accurate the measurement has to be i.e. how large errors can be and remain acceptable. In this case I'd guess the error in your temperature is of order one degree, which is probably fine for this type of experiment.

Where I've needed greater accuracy I use a large water bath and put my experiment in it. Something like:

[image: Water bath]

The idea is that the large thermal mass of the water bath means it cools or heats only very slowly so the temperature can be maintained to a high accuracy. In a lab setting you can buy thermostatically controlled heaters to maintain the water bath temperature, but for a home or school experiment you probably don't need such precision and the thermal inertia of the water bath is enough.

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility is getting a digital thermometer and a computer-controlled heating element. Then setup a feedback loop so that the liquid is maintained at the proper temperature.